# Find productID with beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a URL from this page using BeautifulSoup by searching for the p0662110597086(his id). I've tried several different approaches with BeautifulSoup, including a different html parser, but none of these have been successful.

```
            <a href="#media" class="movie" hpp="act_video">video</a>            <ul>
          <li>identity：<span itemprop="productID">p0662110597086</span></li>
        <li>soll numbers：75</li>
        <li>solds：97</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
html = '''            <a href="#media" class="movie" hpp="act_video">video</a>            <ul>
          <li>identity：<span itemprop="productID">p0662110597086</span></li>
        <li>soll numbers：75</li>
        <li>solds：97</li>
        </ul>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

id_tag = soup.find('span', string='p0662110597086')
a_tag = id_tag.find_previous('a', class_='movie')
```

out:

```
id_tag:  <span itemprop="productID">p0662110597086</span>
a_tag:  <a class="movie" hpp="act_video" href="#media">video</a>
```

> Signature: `find_all_previous(name, attrs, string, limit, **kwargs)`
>
> Signature: `find_previous(name, attrs, string, **kwargs)`
>
> These methods use `.previous_elements` to iterate over the tags and
>   strings that came before it in the document. The `find_all_previous()`
>   method returns all matches, and `find_previous()` only returns the first
>   match